# sometimes test throws Not a valid Inertia error

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, inertiajs

I have the issue that when I run all my tests, some will fail with the error message: `Not a valid Inertia response`. But when running only the testsuite these tests are part of - or individual - they pass without error and I don't know why.

These are my used versions:

- inertiajs/inertia-laravel: v.0.6.11
- laravel/framework: v10.40.0
- phpunit/phpunit: v10.5.5
- php: 8.2

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Inertia\Intern;

use Inertia\Testing\AssertableInertia;
use Tests\TestCase;

class EmailsTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCorrectView()
    {
        $this->get('intern/emails')
            ->assertInertia(
                fn (AssertableInertia $page) => $page
                    ->component('Intern/Emails')
            );
    }
}
```

This is the error the test is failing with:

```
   FAILED  Tests\Inertia\Intern\EmailsTest > correct view                                                                                                AssertionFailedError   
  Not a valid Inertia response.

  at vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Testing/AssertableInertia.php:34
     30▕             PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey('props', $page);
     31▕             PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey('url', $page);
     32▕             PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey('version', $page);
     33▕         } catch (AssertionFailedError $e) {
  ➜  34▕             PHPUnit::fail('Not a valid Inertia response.');
     35▕         }
     36▕ 
     37▕         $instance = static::fromArray($page['props']);
     38▕         $instance->component = $page['component'];

      +3 vendor frames 
  4   tests/Inertia/Intern/EmailsTest.php:27
```

I tried to debug the problem and found the part of the code that throws the error message but I still don't know how to prevent the error from coming up in the first place. So here is what I found while debugging my problem:

The obvious cause of the issue is the function `assertInertia`. This function is generically used to test Inertia routes. Inside this function is the call to the static method `AssertableInertia::fromTestResponse($this)`. Here you find the following line: `$response->assertViewHas('page');`. This assert is failing because the method `responseHasView` from class `\Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse` is testing the following: `isset($this->original) && $this->original instanceof View`, but `$this->original` is not an instance of `View`.

The above chain of events is happening only when the whole testsuite (all tests in the project - without any filtering) are run. Running the test individually or only the testsuite in which the test is part of -> no error. Test passes. Strange.

### Update:

The reason why the test is failing when running multiple tests after one another and not when run individually is because the `Illuminate/Http/Response::setContent()` function is run twice instead of once.

Here is the content of the function as reference:

```php
    public function setContent(mixed $content): static
    {
        $this->original = $content;

        // If the content is "JSONable" we will set the appropriate header and convert
        // the content to JSON. This is useful when returning something like models
        // from routes that will be automatically transformed to their JSON form.
        if ($this->shouldBeJson($content)) {
            $this->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            $content = $this->morphToJson($content);

            if ($content === false) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(json_last_error_msg());
            }
        }

        // If this content implements the "Renderable" interface then we will call the
        // render method on the object so we will avoid any "__toString" exceptions
        // that might be thrown and have their errors obscured by PHP's handling.
        elseif ($content instanceof Renderable) {
            $content = $content->render();
        }

        parent::setContent($content);

        return $this;
    }
```

During the first run of the function the `$content` variable contains an instance of the `Illuminate/View/View` class. During the second run of this function the `$content` contains the rendered HTML.

That's why function `responseHasView` of the `Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse` class the condition `$this->original instanceof View` is not met. Therefore an exception is thrown.

Comment: `$this->withoutMix()` or `$this->withoutVite()` is probably missing from your test, my guess.

Comment: I rerun all my tests while having `$this->withoutVite()` in my Test Case in the setup method, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: When I run `vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Inertia` in the terminal, all tests are green. But when I run `vendor/bin/phpunit` I have 15 failures.

Comment: Run your tests with `$this->withoutErrorHandling();` so if something goes wrong, we can see the real error instead of the error you are getting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly withouting the Exception Handling does not change the error I get in the test.